# PuTTY PSFTP command line works as Admin, fails as User

Tags: putty, psftp

I have an interesting dilemma with PuTTY PSFTP.

Set up...

```
Pageant .60
putty .60
```

Used command:

```
D:\psftp.exe -load myserver.domain.us.com -l User1 -b MyCommand Script
```

This loads PuTTY PSFTP, logs in using the user ID with the help of Pageant and then sends a file using commands in the script.

This works great while logged in as an Admin on the server. 
It fails while logged in as a regular user on the server:

```
"psftp: no hostname specified;"blah blah blah.
```

Including `-v` reveals no further messages.

What possible delta could there be with permissions or other settings between a server Admin and regular user **when it comes to PuTTY**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You load PuTTY stored site `myserver.domain.us.com`.

That is stored in Windows registry of the local account.

If you run the script using a different account, it won't see the site definition.

You have to define the session completely on command line. What you probably even attempted.

- Remove the `-load`;
- Add `-ssh` to make it clear you want to use SSH (but it's default anyway)
- Add `-hostkey=...` with a fingerprint of the SSH host key (you need the latest version of PuTTY for the `-hostkey` switch, but you need to upgrade anyway, the version 0.60 is not secure).

```
D:\psftp.exe -ssh myserver.domain.us.com -hostkey=... -l User1 -b MyCommand Script
```